# Why is realmin > eps(0)?

Tags: matlab, ieee-754

`realmin` "returns the smallest positive normalized floating point number in IEEE double precision". `eps(X)` "is the positive distance from ABS(X) to the
next larger in mangitude floating point number of the same precision as X".

If I am interpreting the above documentation correctly, then `realmin` -- the smallest positive number that can be represented -- must be smaller than `eps
(0)`. But:

```
>> realmin; % 2.2251e-308
>> eps(0);  % 4.9407e-324
```

Obviously, `eps(0)`, which is even smaller, can be represented too. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: "must be smaller than `eps(0)`". Nothing can be smaller than `eps(0)`. `eps(0)` is the minimum quantity to add to 0 to obtain the next possible number. Hence `eps(0)` is the smallest representable number. At best you could think that `eps(0)` should be equal to `realmin`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a floating point issue. You should go read up on [denormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).

Briefly, `realmin` returns the smallest positive *normalized* floating point number. But it's possible to have denormal numbers that are smaller than this and still representable in floating point, which is what `eps(0)` returns.

**Quick explanation of denormal numbers**

A binary floating point number looks like this:

```
1.abcdef * 2^M
```

where `abcdefg` are each either 0 or 1, and `M` is a number in the range -1022 <= *M* <= 1023. These are called *normalized* floating point numbers. The smallest possible normalized floating point number is `1 * 2^(-1022)`.

The denormal numbers looks like this

```
0.abcdef * 2^(-1022)
```

so they can take values that are smaller than the smallest possible normalized floating point number. The denormal numbers linearly interpolate between `-realmin` and `realmin`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is a matter of definition, this is what I see in the documentation of eps:

```
For all X of class double such that abs(X) <= realmin, eps(X) = 2^(-1074)
```